# jQuery - on hover grandchild or great grandchild, control parent's style recursively

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a minimum 4 level menu (to unlimited). My wish is to create a general recursive action over the menu with jQuery. When I hover a child element, the parent will increase in height, same result I'd like also when hovering any grand-child or great-grand-child, the same parent element to remain increased in height, not the grand-child or great-grand-child.

I have tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/dTqX3/

It looks like I need something else instead of

`$(this).parent().parent().parent().find("a:first")`

which works incorrectly.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Events propagate up to parent elements by default. Why not just add your event to the parent or grandparent instead?

Comment: Because I will have more "parent" elements (on the first level), and I want the height increase to be resulted only on the parent where I'm hovering it's descendants, not on all the parent elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some great direction from @Jon (thank's a lot!) I've tried with functions like [.parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) and [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/). The expected results still wasn't found, but I had the possibility to have an idea how are working this recursive parent countings. I kept the `.parents()` way and added `.last()`. The next code did the trick:

```
$(this).parents('ul > li').last().find("a:first").attr('style', 'height:55px;line-height:55px;');
```

This is the important part:

```
$(this).parents('ul > li').last().find("a:first")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/upk7X/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your DOM structure, you need climb up the tree to an `<ul>` ancestor (the container of the item being hovered) and find the anchor that is its sibling (the higher-level menu item that caused this container to show), which translates to:

```
$(this).closest("ul").siblings("a")
```

With this change [it seems to work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/5uSQD/).

Comment: Wow! A very nice aproach. The only problem is that on grand-child elements hover the Children #3 will increase also in height and on great-grand-child element hover will increase in height also the Grandchild #3. I would like to increase only Parent #2 in current example. Of course all of this dynamically, thinking to add more parent "in the future".

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich: Probably I don't quite understand what exactly you want to achieve, this behavior seemed logical to me. But it shouldn't be difficult to adapt in any case.

Comment: I'd like to be changed only the parent element(s), not also child or grand-child element(s). Only `Parent #2` in the example code.